# IF statements with OR operator not working

Tags: php, if-statement, or-operator

```
if($action == "send"){
$_POST['name'] =        $name ;
$_POST['email'] =       $email ;
$_POST['phone'] =       $phone  ;


  if(!empty($name) || !empty($email) || !empty($phone)){

  .....
 } else {

  $msg = 'All fields required';

}
```

//whatever I do only shows $msg.

//already tried that too

```
  if(!empty($_POST['name']) || !empty($_POST['email']) || !empty($_POST['phone'])){
  ....
   }
```

What Im trying to do is a form that email me the data, and I want all fields to be filled so maybe Im writing the if statement the wrong way.
sorry if I didnt explained well before.

Comment: Did you print the $_POST and you are sure it has the values?

Comment: try doing a print_r($_POST) to see whats inside post global var and then see if your if should result in 'true'. Also shouldn't your if test be with && instead of ||. Makes no sense with ||.

Comment: We can't answer you question without more informations. This if statement and your logical formula have so problems, so it comes from the code above it.

Comment: What Im trying to do is a form that email me the data, and I want all fields to be filled so maybe Im writing the if statement the wrong way. sorry if I didnt explained well before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code reads:

> If name is not empty, or email is not empty, or phone is not empty

This means that as long as *at least one* of them are non-empty, then you're good!

Pretty sure that's not what you meant. You want:

> If name is not empty, AND email is not empty, AND phone is not empty

Use `&&` instead of `||` and it should just work!

Comment: `$_POST['name'] = $name;` is wrong. Remove it. If anything you may do `$name = $_POST['name']`, but personally I prefer to avoid "mirroring" user input variables because it serves as a reminder that it is user input and therefore more unsafe than usual.

Comment: I tried this before, and didnt work, but now I tried with the advice you gave me: use && instead ||. worked perfectly well now, thanks mate you saved my life hehehehe

Answer (score 1):

I think you're getting confused by all the negatives involved here. I suspect what you're after is:

```
if (!(empty($name) || empty($email) || empty($phone))) {
    ...
} else {
    $msg = 'All fields required';
}
```

Which would be better written (in my opinion) as:

```
if (empty($name) || empty($email) || empty($phone)) {
    $msg = 'All fields required';
} else {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if($name=='' || $email=='' || $phone=='')
{
    $msg='All fields required';
}
else 
{
    ..............
}
```